# How to connect android phone to a web service run on local server?

Tags: android, mysql, database, web-services, tomcat

I had tried on my emulator, it can connect to the java web service I created. But when I try to access from my android device, it does not work. Is anyone know how to get through this?

Another question is, by doing this way, is that possible 2 android devices access to the same database?

I am using Tomcat server and MySQL database. The web service is actually use to get the data from the MySQL database and pass to my android phone.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can connect your local webservices in Android device. If there will be any way then I am interested to know that. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run the service on your LAN IP instead of as localhost and connect the phone through wifi?

It can also be possible to connect via setting proxy.

Comment: Can you tell me, is there any way to achieve this if I have only a laptop (on which the service is running) and the phone. Can I achieve it using WiFi Hotspot or some other tool. Both the devices have WiFi and I don't have any other device but the two. I know we can do it if we have one other device so that, WiFi hotspot is running on it and connect the laptop and the Android phone to the Hotspot.

Comment: Hi, you can go to settings of phone/emulator ->Mobile Networks -> AccessPoint Name and add an access point and put your proxy settings in there,

Comment: In your case you can point it to your machine IP address and connect to Internet via your device

Comment: Sorry @Prashant, but I have no idea how to do it. Can you guide me the way, plz. There are a number of entries to be filled in the **New APN** category like `APN`, `Proxy`, `Port`, `Username`, `Password` and more. So, if **IP** of my Laptop is say `111.111.111.111` and **port** is `80`. What is to do now. My original question is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674407/)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to make sure your web service is visible through the IP of the machine that is hosting it. You could test this by trying to access the web server from another desktop using the IP and whatever port number it might be listening on.

If it is possible then it should just be a case of connecting your phone to the same network segment (router) the machine hosting the web server is on and use the IP (and port number) of the web server.

There should be no problem at all 2 android devices accessing the same server assuming the database is setup correctly and you are using the correct client code.

Comment: Sir I've tried following your instruction. My WebServiceUrl is "http://localhost:50857/api/Customer/"; but whenever I tried to access it in my mobile phone, it does not display anything. I even changed the word 'localhost' to my laptop's IP address hoping I can access it in my mobile but still wasn't able to do so.

Comment: Are you connected to the wifi on the same network segment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IP address 10.0.2.2? That is localhost on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use KSOAP2 library to access WebService, google it for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a public URL for your server running on a specific port on localhost.

At my work place I could access the local server by using the local IP address of my machine in the app, as most of the other answers suggest. But at home I wasn't able to do that for some reason. After trying many answers and spending many hours, I came across https://ngrok.com. It is pretty straight forward. Just download it from within the folder do:

```
ngrok portnumber
```

( from command prompt in windows)

```
./ngrok portnumber
```

(from terminal in linux)

This will give you a public URL for your local server running on that port number on localhost. You can include in your app and debug it using that URL.

You can securely expose a local web server to the internet and capture all traffic for detailed inspection. You can share the URL with your colleague developer also who might be working remotely and can debug the App/Server interaction.

Hope this saves someone's time someday.

Answer (score -1):

When it works on emulator then it should work on real device. Perhaps it is something about proxy or network issue.

For your second question. Do you use local database for client like SQLite? If yes then each device has its own DB which you need to sync to server DB (MySQL) through web services.