# Connecting an Android phone to a local server w/o a third device

Tags: android, lan

I know the question line is a bit ambiguous, but I could not think of a better one.

My question is:
I have an Android app that makes an `HTTP` request, the server is currently running on local. So, when I am in my office I connect both my laptop (on which the server is) and my phone on a same LAN network. And make that HTTP request using the hitting on the `IP` of the laptop.

This is all fine, I wanna know is when I reach home I don't have a WiFi running, neither do I have a third device (so that, I may use it as a WiFi Hotspot). So, is there any tool by which I can achieve this. Both the Laptop and the phone has WiFi.

Comment: Do you take your laptop home? If so, you can configure it to be the hotspot.

Comment: Yes, please elaborate how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Connectify Me](http://www.connectify.me/)...install it in you laptop, and it will make its wifi receiver to work as wifi broadcaster...than you can connect your android deivce to this broadcasted network just as you normally do with other wifi networks.

And then hopefully you will be able to access you server hosted on laptop from you android device...

Comment: Will definitely try this.